# Wrapping submit button with a form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have very interesting idea. Is it possible to, using a JQuery, create a form wrapped around some element in html? For instance lets say I have this element `<submit></submit>`

```
<a href="">...</a>
```

and once someone clicks on actionlink, it waits for 1-2 secs and wraps submit button with form, something like `<form><submit></submit></form>`? Is it possible to do so.

Comment: There is no `<submit>` element. And have you read the jQuery documentation at all, or searched Google. http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Why would you have input elements to submit without a form though?   If you're starting with invalid HTML, perhaps starting the fix there is the more valid attempt.

Comment: The thins is I have a very odd situation here. My dialog box is inside form and also submit, but since submit is inside a dialog box, which is inside a form, DOM is somewhere else, can't fire once clicked on submit at all.

Comment: This may be simply a DOM handler problem then.  Look into attaching the button action to something that is NOT created by the DOM, such as the root document,  `$(document).on('click','.myButtonClass', {} ,function(e){ //do something });`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" />

$('a').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('<form></form>').append($('#submit')).appendTo('body');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

yup:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('<form><submit></submit></form>').appendTo('body')
    }, 1000);
})
```